# How to extract and process nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm struggling to extract rules array from a JSON test report. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
// input
const json = {
"data": {
    "allTests": [
        {
          "id": "foo",
          "testStatus": "PASS",
          "ruleList": [
            {
              "outcome": "PASS",
              "name": "Image should be awesome"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "bar",
          "testStatus": "FAIL",
          "ruleList": [
            {
              "outcome": "HARD_FAIL",
              "name": "Image should be awesome"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "baz",
          "testStatus": "FAIL",
          "ruleList": [
            {
              "outcome": "SOFT_FAIL",
              "name": "Image should be awesome"
            }
          ]
        },
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected outcome:

```js
[{
    "name": "Image should be awesome",
    "HARD_FAIL": 1,
    "SOFT_FAIL": 1,
    "PASS": 1
}]
```

Comment: The end result should be array or an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I took the liberty to work only with `json.data.allTests`)*

What I would do:

1. Extract all rules in all `ruleList` with `chain`
2. While you do that, revert the `outcome` property e.g. `{outcome: 'PASS'}` => `{PASS: 1}`
3. Group by `name`, summing up all outcomes *(assuming that e.g. `PASS: 2` is possible)*
4. Extract all values

```js
const with_ramda =
  pipe(
    chain(x => x.ruleList.map(({outcome, name}) => ({[outcome]: 1, name}))),
    reduceBy(({name: _, ...acc}, x) => mergeWith(add, acc, x), {}, prop('name')),
    values);
        
console.log(with_ramda(input));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>const {pipe, chain, reduceBy, mergeWith, add, prop, values} = R;</script>

<script>
const input =
  [ { "id": "foo"
    , "testStatus": "PASS"
    , "ruleList":
        [ { "outcome": "PASS"
          , "name": "Image should be awesome"
          }
        ]
    }
  , { "id": "bar"
    , "testStatus": "FAIL"
    , "ruleList":
        [ { "outcome": "HARD_FAIL"
          , "name": "Image should be awesome"
          }
        ]
    }
  , { "id": "baz"
    , "testStatus": "FAIL"
    , "ruleList":
        [ { "outcome": "SOFT_FAIL"
          , "name": "Image should be awesome"
          }
        ]
    }
  ];
</script>
```

---

In case you're interested a vanilla solution is also possible and isn't necessarily more complicated:

```js
const with_vanillajs =
  xs =>
    Object.values(
      xs.flatMap(x => x.ruleList)
        .reduce((acc, {outcome, name}) =>
          ( acc[name] = acc[name] || {name}
          , acc[name][outcome] = (acc[name][outcome] || 0) + 1
          , acc), {}));
          

console.log(with_vanillajs(input));
```

```html
<script>
const input =
  [ { "id": "foo"
    , "testStatus": "PASS"
    , "ruleList":
        [ { "outcome": "PASS"
          , "name": "Image should be awesome"
          }
        ]
    }
  , { "id": "bar"
    , "testStatus": "FAIL"
    , "ruleList":
        [ { "outcome": "HARD_FAIL"
          , "name": "Image should be awesome"
          }
        ]
    }
  , { "id": "baz"
    , "testStatus": "FAIL"
    , "ruleList":
        [ { "outcome": "SOFT_FAIL"
          , "name": "Image should be awesome"
          }
        ]
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the `ruleList` arrays using R.chain, group them by the `name`, and convert to pairs of `[name, array of rules]`, map the pairs, and convert each pair to object. Use R.countBy to calculate the outcomes' scores:

```js
const { countBy, prope, pipe, chain, prop, groupBy, toPairs, map } = R

const countByOutcome = countBy(prop('outcome'))

const fn = pipe(
  chain(prop('ruleList')), // flatten the ruleList
  groupBy(prop('name')), // group by the name
  toPairs, // convert to [name, values] pairs
  map(([name, val]) => ({ // map the pairs to objects 
    name,
    ...countByOutcome(val) // count the outcomes
  })),
)

const input = [{"id":"foo","testStatus":"PASS","ruleList":[{"outcome":"PASS","name":"Image should be awesome"}]},{"id":"bar","testStatus":"FAIL","ruleList":[{"outcome":"HARD_FAIL","name":"Image should be awesome"}]},{"id":"baz","testStatus":"FAIL","ruleList":[{"outcome":"SOFT_FAIL","name":"Image should be awesome"}]}]
        
console.log(fn(input))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I just saw this question, went off and coded my answer, got sidetracked by a combinators question, came back to post it, and yours is here with exactly the same technique, and only slightly different code!  Timing!

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer similar to the one from Ori Drori because it's just enough different to be interesting.

First of all, the one example you gave is really not enough to demonstrate exactly what you want to do, but several other answers make the same assumptions I do, so I'm guessing we're all right.  But to be explicit, I'm assuming that:

- the `1`s in the result are counts and not boolean markers that simply indicate that the outcome is included.  My test data checks this by including a second "PASS" scenario for the name "Image should be awesome".
- There can be more than one `name` in the data.  Your example shows only one.  I added another to my test case.
- The output objects are grouped by these names, and not by, for example, by other fields parallel to `allTests`.

With those assumptions, I wrote this:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  path (['data', 'allTests']),
  chain (prop ('ruleList')),
  groupBy (prop ('name')),
  map (pluck ('outcome')),
  map (countBy (identity)),
  toPairs,
  map (([name, rest]) => ({name, ...rest})),
)

const json = {data: {allTests: [{id: "foo", testStatus: "PASS", ruleList: [{outcome: "PASS", name: "Image should be awesome"}, {outcome: "HARD_FAIL", name: "Image should be chocolate"}]}, {id: "bar", testStatus: "FAIL", ruleList: [{outcome: "HARD_FAIL", name: "Image should be awesome"}]}, {id: "baz", testStatus: "FAIL", ruleList: [{outcome: "SOFT_FAIL", name: "Image should be awesome"}, {outcome: "PASS", name: "Image should be awesome"}]}]}}

console .log (transform (json))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, path, chain, prop, groupBy, map, pluck, countBy, identity, toPairs} = R </script>
```

I tend to write transformation functions step-by-step, each time trying to move my output a little closer to my final goal.  So I wrote this going down the pipeline.  There may be easier ways to change these, or combine steps.  Ori Drori extracted a useful function, and we could do so as well here.  But I think it reads reasonably well, and you can check what it does by commenting out any tail of functions in the pipeline to see the intermediate results.

If you're a point-free fetishist, you can replace the last line of the function with `map (apply (useWith (mergeRight, [objOf('name')])))`.  I don't see the need, but that would lead to an entirely point-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well this might work:

```
var Result = [{}];
json.data.allTests.forEach (Entry => {
    var Rules = Entry.ruleList || [];

    Rules.forEach (Rule => {
        var { outcome, name } = Rule;

        console.log ({ outcome, name });

        Result [ 0 ] [ outcome ] = 1;
        Result [ 0 ].name = name;
    });
});
console.log ({ Result });
```